# ALWAYS RUN VSCODE AS ROOT

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal, root

Currently, I'm running vscode from the terminal with the following command:

*sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"*

(I'm using POP OS) However, how can I perhaps add it to PATH, so instead of the command above, I can issue the following command:

vscode

In order to always run it as root?

Comment: Why would you *ever* want to run vscode as root?  Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I'm installing a vscode extension that requires administrative privileges. I've heard a lot about it being a "bad idea," however, can you point me to any resources for further information.

Comment: Running stuff with administrator privs is how malware and viruses work and spread -- Windows prevalence for always requiring admin is why its security is such a problem.  Any vscode extension that requires it is likely malware.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your 'visudo' file and add the full path to the application:

```
<YOURUSERID> ALL = NOPASSWD:<FULLPATHTOVSCODE>
```

But this is really a great way to do something bad. Sudo should be used rarely and if you are using it frequently there is a better way to do what you are doing.